# A CUDA parallel program help needed

Tags: c++, cuda, parallel-processing

I am new to CUDA and parallel programming. I want to do a double parallel part in CUDA can someone help me out here. Sorry for posting here but i am a little confused and could not find any nice tutorial or help for it.
I want to make a function such that it works parallel in CUDA and then i want to make another function of CUDA that is called in parallel from that function is it possible in kernel function of CUDA ?

**EDIT**

for example i have two kernel functions `my_prog` and `my prog_1` i am calling them like this

```
main_function
{
    my_prog<<core,threads>>();
}

my_prog()
{
   //here i want to call my_prog_1 in parallel
   my_prog_1<<core,threads>>();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to learn how to write CUDA programs, I would suggest taking some of the tutorials that are available.

NVIDIA has a [webinar page](https://developer.nvidia.com/gpu-computing-webinars) with a variety of tutorials.

For starters, these two webinars will give you a basic intro to CUDA with enough knowledge to be able to write CUDA programs that run fast:

GPU Computing using CUDA C – An Introduction (2010)
An introduction to the basics of GPU computing using CUDA C. Concepts will be illustrated with walkthroughs of code samples. No prior GPU Computing experience required

GPU Computing using CUDA C – Advanced 1 (2010)
First level optimization techniques such as global memory optimization, and processor utilization. Concepts will be illustrated using real code examples

It would be 2 hours well spent if you want to learn how to write CUDA programs.

**EDIT:** 
What you're describing here is CUDA Dynamic Parallelism.  It requires a device with  CUDA compute capability of 3.5 (today).

You can find a complete user's guide for it [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/pdf/CUDA_Dynamic_Parallelism_Programming_Guide.pdf)

Comment: Thankx for the answer, i can write a simple CUDA program just want some guideline on how to write a CUDA program that can do parallel computing on a double. For example I have a kernel function that i have called in parallel from that kernel function i want to call another kernel or device function further in parallel, is it possible ? Thank you

Comment: If you have a specific coding question, perhaps you should show an example of the code you have written.  Computing on `double` data types should not be a problem for cc 1.3 or newer devices.  You can call 2 kernels in parallel, this is called concurrent execution.  This will only be useful if the kernels are relatively small.

Comment: please see edits, i have updated sorry for the misunderstanding before